# Кодировка assert при тестировании приложения

Tags: python, тестирование, flask, юнит-тесты

Пытаюсь написать простой тест для приложения на flask, но при `assert`'e происходит что-то неладное.

Код теста:

```
def test_empty(self):
    res = self.app.get('/')
    assert 'В базе нет ссылок.' in res.data
```

При запуске теста получается следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал добавлять `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` в начало файла, пробовал оборачивать строку в `unicode()`, пробовал `.encode('utf-8')` и т.п., но без изменений. Возможно, не понимаю саму природу ошибки.

**UPDATE:** Питон версии 2.7.3. Ось Windows 7 (английская).

Comment: Сама природа ошибки зависит от версии питона и операционной системы

Comment: @andreymal Добавил версии в вопрос.

Comment: вероятно это из-за кодировки в терминале

Comment: @dizballanze Такая проблема только с питоном. golang, nodejs и т.п. логируют кириллицу исправно.

Comment: А пробовали `# -*- coding: cp1251 -*-` или `# -*- coding: cp866 -*-`?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю что:

1) стоит сохранить питоновский файл в кодировке utf-8 (с помошью настроек Вашего текстового редактора)

2) добавить в начало файла

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

3) для русских букв использовать юникодные строки. Вместо:

```
assert 'В базе нет ссылок.' -> assert u'В базе нет ссылок.'
```